# SFML. The procedure entry point inflateReset2 could not be located in the dynamic link library zlib1.dll

Tags: c++, mingw, sfml, zlib, msys2

I'm studying SFML. I work with msys2 mingw64. When working with windows, shapes, textures, there were no problems, everything was compiled and worked until i`ve decided to implement my own textbox. When using sf::Font, sf::Text program compiles successfully but at startup the error window displays **"The procedure entry point inflateReset2 could not be located in the dynamic link library zlib1.dll"**
To generalize, compilation is done like this:

```
main: main.o
    g++ main.o -o main -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lfreetype -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp -c -DSFML_STATIC
```

I've tried to google this but for now cant find anything that fits me.
Some says that downloading the newest or maybe i should say the fittest version of zlib1 could be the point but for doing that i need to understand which file i need to replace (reinstalling zlib using pacman doesn't help i should say)
Reinstallation of SFML also doesn't help.

Should also mention that in the begging of working with Text, Font, etc there was another problem as i missed freetype lib when compiling program. I got it using pacman, added to makefile and when got the problem i've mentioned above.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: My expectation is you have multiple versions of this dll in your PATH environment variable and your OS finds the wrong one ( could be an older or newer one that is incompatible with the static libraries that you are using)

Comment: ***I've tried to google this but for now cant find anything that fits me. Some says that downloading the newest or maybe i should say the fittest version of zlib1 could be the point but for doing that i need to understand which file i need to replace (reinstalling zlib using pacman doesn't help i should say) Reinstallation of SFML also doesn't help.*** Ahh, I see why your searches failed. Your search should not mention zlib or SFML at all. Your problem is most likely "DLL Hell"

Comment: You probably should understand how your OS searches for dlls first: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

Comment: @drescherjm i've tried my best reading this but i guess i'm not getting closer to understand what is going on (:

*My expectation is you have multiple versions of this dll in your PATH environment variable and your OS finds the wrong one ( could be an older or newer one that is incompatible with the static libraries that you are using)* that is true, there are couple of them.
is there any possibility i can find the right one and point system on it?

Comment: Do a search of your filesystem. See if there are more than 1 `zlib1.dll` installed. Make sure that your sfml and all other dependencies were installed via `pacman` in your `ming64` terminal and no other method.

Comment: @drescherjm sorry for being away. I'm totally sure that sfml and all other dependencies were installed using pacman. I do have couple of ```zlib1```  but i don't really understand if it can cause any problems since i added msys64\mingw64\bin to the path variable.

Comment: Make sure that the `msys64\mingw64\bin` in your PATH is before any other folder that contains a `zlib1.dll`